# Swift 3.1 Coredata Sorting Alphabetically Ascending but Keep Records Starting with Numbers in the Beginning

Tags: ios, swift, sorting, core-data

I have used coredata in one of my iOS projects. I have a table named "Books" (columns: title, author, status, publishdate) and I need to fetch records in a way that they are ordered by column Title in ascending mode. This is what I have written to accomplish it:

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>.init(entityName: "Books")

let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "title", ascending: true)

fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sort]

do {
    let result = try coreViewContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
} catch let err as NSError {
    print(err.debugDescription)
}
```

What if i have some books with titles like "100 Stories, 20 Movies, 300 Men"? I want such titles to be at the beginning of the result array. Currently such records lie in between.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend converting the CoreData result to an array of book objects (which I assume you do eventually anyway) implementing a custom sorter function.  Something like the function below:

```
static func sortByTitle(books: [Book]) -> [Book]{
    return books.sorted(by: sorterForTitlesAlphaNumeric)
}
```

The implementation for sorterForTitlesAlphaNumeric would look something like this:

```
//Compare this book's title to that book's title
static func sorterForTitlesAlphaNumeric(this : Book, that: Book) -> Bool {
    return this.title < that.title
}
```

That will give you a finer grain control than trying to use the pre-baked `NSSortDescriptor`.  That way if later down the road you decide to filter based on title and then publish date you can change the above function to

```
    //Compare this book's title to that book's title
static func sorterForTitlesAlphaNumeric(this : Book, that: Book) -> Bool {
    if this.title == that.title {
        return this.publishDate < that.publishDate 
    }
    return this.title < that.title
}
```